# Cache task in AzDO is timing out

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

My cache task fails with a timeout exception, wasn't able to find any information on the web

```
2021-11-19T13:12:49.5440178Z ##[section]Starting: Cache Maven local repo
2021-11-19T13:12:49.5444463Z ==============================================================================
2021-11-19T13:12:49.5444700Z Task         : Cache
2021-11-19T13:12:49.5444880Z Description  : Cache files between runs
2021-11-19T13:12:49.5445073Z Version      : 2.0.1
2021-11-19T13:12:49.5445247Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-11-19T13:12:49.5445454Z Help         : https://aka.ms/pipeline-caching-docs
2021-11-19T13:12:49.5445913Z ==============================================================================
2021-11-19T13:12:50.3859003Z Resolving key:
2021-11-19T13:12:50.3867990Z  - maven      [string]
2021-11-19T13:12:50.3868628Z  - "Linux"    [string]
2021-11-19T13:12:50.3869252Z  - **/pom.xml [file pattern; matches: 1]
2021-11-19T13:12:50.3870147Z    - s/pom.xml --> 425BE14263A590554133E4A4AE3B095D0207EE19CADB68111111A8623073C9
2021-11-19T13:12:50.3870747Z Resolved to: maven|"Linux"|6BG0VLzocHR1ABXQNLQ+q7oxXHj2Ln9xNBME=
2021-11-19T13:12:50.3872532Z Resolving restore key:
2021-11-19T13:12:50.3873112Z  - maven   [string]
2021-11-19T13:12:50.3873653Z  - "Linux" [string]
2021-11-19T13:12:50.3874064Z Resolved to: maven|"Linux"|**
2021-11-19T13:12:50.3874469Z Resolving restore key:
2021-11-19T13:12:50.3874998Z  - maven [string]
2021-11-19T13:12:50.3875403Z Resolved to: maven|**
2021-11-19T13:12:50.4071086Z ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session 018d9b8b-7e2e-4eb4-9081-60a8aac6ca19
2021-11-19T13:12:50.4271999Z Getting a pipeline cache artifact with one of the following fingerprints:
2021-11-19T13:12:50.4272751Z Fingerprint: `maven|"Linux"|6BG0VLzocHR1ABXQNLQ+CkcxTTgq7oxXHj2Ln9xNBME=`
2021-11-19T13:12:50.4273230Z Fingerprint: `maven|"Linux"|**`
2021-11-19T13:12:50.4273649Z Fingerprint: `maven|**`
2021-11-19T13:12:51.4866539Z There is a cache hit: `maven|"Linux"|6BG0VLzocHR1ABXQNLQ+CkcxTTgq7oxXHj2Ln9xNBME=`
2021-11-19T13:12:51.4878034Z Used scope: 1506;0fc5062f-55dd-476b-baba-8952a15401e7;refs/heads/EOD_STORES;52820a17-3ace-4f9e-ba77-2330a6eccacb
2021-11-19T13:12:51.5808454Z Entry found at fingerprint: `maven|"Linux"|6BG0VLzocHR1ABXQNLQ+CkcxTTgq7oxXHj2Ln9xNBME=`
2021-11-19T13:13:51.9289494Z [https://vb8vsblobprodsu6weus46.blob.core.windows.net/db908636dc538642c896c6b0557076a854/1F68E25AD7A9B91792F6DE976146515E90F7488470FD5DB9D2166AEB7C2451A201?sv=2019-07-07&sr=b&spr=https&se=2021-11-20T14:07:21Z&sp=r&rscl=x-e2eid-7f1caaa0-030b4341-adf321f6-8515e4e2-session-018d9b8b-7e2e4eb4-908160a8-aac6ca19] Try 1/5, Task was requested to be canceled.
2021-11-19T13:45:52.9504822Z ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 3 events with X-TFS-Session 018d9b8b-7e2e-4eb4-9081-60a8aac6ca19
2021-11-19T13:45:52.9581543Z ##[error]Attempt timed out after 00:01:00.
2021-11-19T13:45:52.9618987Z ##[section]Finishing: Cache Maven local repo
```

Comment: In my project, the cache takes about 8 seconds to fetch ~500MB. Until it doesn't. Today I've seen an average of 10-12 minutes for this step. Very frustrating.